# Get Response in Postman For Update

Tags: ef-code-first, postman, asp.net-core-2.2

I am using IActionResult in Web API Controller and heating method from Postman ,My Functionality is working but not getting success response .
My Code is:

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route ("MarkAsInActive")]
    public IActionResult MarkAsInActive (Pousada pousada)
    {
        try
        {
            var x =  Service.MarkAsInActive(pousada.ID, pousada.IsActive);

            if (x != null)
            {
                return Ok(x);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest ();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Response in Postman  is:
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to https://localhost:44303/api/Pousada/MarkAsInActive.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General

But I want Reponse in Json format as like:
{
"ID":"43956f24-ddcc-41b1-a29b-71f717c6fb0e",
"IsActive":"true"
}

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the error message is self-descriptive. Since I assume you don't want to have a headache installing the valid SSL certificate on your machine just disable certificate verification setting in your postman like described [here](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/launching_postman/settings/)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect over "https". Is this correct?
If yes, and you are using a self signed certificate. Try to turn off certificate verification in Postman over File->Settings(General Tab)
[image]

Comment: already disable SSL certificate verification.But still showing that message.

Comment: are you quite sure, that you are using https?
Also please check your configured port

Comment: Ok,I have got Solution